Stitch pictures from rotating camera
I am writing a homography by rotation project by following the example here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html#tutorial_homography_Demo5
For my project, I capture two photos using an XR environment. For each photo, I have 1.) a rotation quaternion given to me by the device, and 2.) a 4x4 camera intrinsics projection matrix of the XR scene. For my purposes I am assuming camera position(translation) does not change.
When I run my script, the stitch fails.

Can someone show me where I am going wrong? I believe this is not working due to a lack of understanding of matrices, or improper conversion of camera projection matrix to camera intrinsics.
Script:
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Python 2/3 compatibility
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

def quaternion_to_rotation_matrix(q):
    x, y, z, w = q['x'], q['y'], q['z'], q['w']
    return np.array([
        [1 - 2*(y**2 + z**2), 2*(x*y - z*w), 2*(x*z + y*w)],
        [2*(x*y + z*w), 1 - 2*(x**2 + z**2), 2*(y*z - x*w)],
        [2*(x*z - y*w), 2*(y*z + x*w), 1 - 2*(x**2 + y**2)]
    ])

def basicPanoramaStitching(img1Path, img2Path):
    img1 = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(img1Path))
    img2 = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(img2Path))

    if img1 is None or img2 is None:
        print("Error loading images.")
        return

    # Rotation quaternions from deviceOrientation event
    q1 = {'w': -0.7968594431877136, 'x': 0.0034535229206085205, 'y': 0.6041417717933655, 'z': -0.004005712922662497}  # Quaternion for camera 1
    q2 = {'w': -0.6669896245002747, 'x': 0.0010529130231589079, 'y': -0.7450388669967651, 'z': 0.00638939393684268}  # Quaternion for camera 2

    # Position data of camera 
    pos1 = {'x': 0, 'y': 2, 'z': 0}
    pos2 = {'x': 0, 'y': 2, 'z': 0}

    # Convert quaternion to rotation matrix
    R1 = quaternion_to_rotation_matrix(q1)
    R2 = quaternion_to_rotation_matrix(q2)

    # Print rotation matrices
    print("R1:\n", R1)
    print("R2:\n", R2)

    # Construct transformation matrices
    c1Mo = np.eye(4)
    c2Mo = np.eye(4)
    c1Mo[0:3, 0:3] = R1
    c2Mo[0:3, 0:3] = R2
    c1Mo[0:3, 3] = [pos1['x'], pos1['y'], pos1['z']]
    c2Mo[0:3, 3] = [pos2['x'], pos2['y'], pos2['z']]

    # Raw intrinsics from the device (16-element column-major array).
    # This is a 16 dimensional column-major 4x4 projection matrix that gives 
    # the scene camera the same field of view as the rendered camera feed.
    raw_intrinsics = [2.5618553161621094, 0, 0, 0, 
                      0, 1.4930813312530518, 0, 0, 
                      0, 0, -1.0000009536743164, -1, 
                      0, 0, -0.010000004433095455, 0]

    # Convert to a 4x4 row-major matrix
    intrinsics_4x4 = np.array(raw_intrinsics).reshape((4, 4)).T

    # Extract the 3x3 camera intrinsic matrix directly from the 4x4 matrix
    cameraMatrix = intrinsics_4x4[:3, :3]

    # Since this is a projection matrix, adjust cx and cy based on the third column if necessary
    fx, fy = cameraMatrix[0, 0], cameraMatrix[1, 1]
    cx, cy = cameraMatrix[0, 2], cameraMatrix[1, 2]

    # Adjusting cameraMatrix to a proper intrinsic format if needed
    cameraMatrix = np.array([[fx, 0, cx], [0, fy, cy], [0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)

    print("Camera Matrix:\n", cameraMatrix)

    # Compute rotation displacement
    R2_transpose = R2.transpose()
    R_2to1 = np.dot(R1, R2_transpose)

    # Print the difference in rotation matrices
    print("R_2to1 (Difference in rotation matrices):\n", R_2to1)

    # Compute homography
    H = cameraMatrix.dot(R_2to1).dot(np.linalg.inv(cameraMatrix))
    H = H / H[2, 2]

    print("Homography:\n", H)

    # Apply the homography to the second image to visualize the transformation
    transformed_img2 = cv.warpPerspective(img2, H, (img2.shape[1] * 2, img2.shape[0]))
    
    # Visualize the transformed second image
    cv.imshow("Transformed Image 2", transformed_img2)
    
    # Stitch images
    img_stitch = cv.warpPerspective(img2, H, (img2.shape[1] * 2, img2.shape[0]))
    img_stitch[0:img1.shape[0], 0:img1.shape[1]] = img1

    img_space = np.zeros((img1.shape[0], 50, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    img_compare = cv.hconcat([img1, img_space, img2])

    cv.imshow("Final", img_compare)
    cv.imshow("Panorama", img_stitch)
    cv.waitKey(0)

def main():
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Code for homography tutorial. Example 5: basic panorama stitching from a rotating camera.")
    parser.add_argument("-I1", "--image1", help="path to first image", default="my-capture-135347.jpg")
    parser.add_argument("-I2", "--image2", help="path to second image", default="my-capture-135408.jpg")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print("Panorama Stitching Started")
    basicPanoramaStitching(args.image1, args.image2)
    print("Panorama Stitching Completed Successfully")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Debugging outputs:
R1:
 [[ 2.69993348e-01 -2.21114543e-03 -9.62859819e-01]
 [ 1.05568153e-02  9.99944055e-01  6.63907698e-04]
 [ 9.62804484e-01 -1.03439817e-02  2.70001586e-01]]
R2:
 [[-0.11024748  0.0069544   0.99387984]
 [-0.01009224  0.99991613 -0.00811613]
 [-0.99385293 -0.01092526 -0.11016804]]
Camera Matrix:
 [[2.5618553 0.        0.       ]
 [0.        1.4930813 0.       ]
 [0.        0.        1.       ]]
R_2to1 (Difference in rotation matrices):
 [[-0.98674843  0.0028789  -0.16223314]
 [ 0.00644999  0.99974826 -0.02148971]
 [ 0.16213043 -0.02225134 -0.9865186 ]]
Homography:
 [[ 1.000233   -0.00500717  0.42129751]
 [-0.00381051 -1.01341045  0.03252436]
 [-0.06415118  0.01510662  1.        ]]

Input Photos:
my-capture-135347.jpg:

my-capture-135408.jpg:


just saying: a homography can't do panoramas beyond 180 degrees. beyond that, you need proper map projections like equirectangular. be aware of that.

I am no expert here on panoramas. These images do not look like panoramas nor do I see why a map projection would be needed for them.  Stitching two photos like these seems pointless to put into panorama, unless the camera "distortion" is severe. Can you not just get control points and find the homography to warp one to another (under perspective) and stitch that way.  I would appreciate further edification.

I think for a keypoint-based stitching ut might be not enough well textured overlap (but still some chance). To my knowledge, for pure roration around the camera center, a perfect stirching could be possible with perspective transformationation. But I don't know how to conpute the 2D transformation from the 3D rotation parameters directly.

might be as simple as H = K @ R @ inv(K) or some variation of it

Feature detection indeed is not robust enough to guarantee stitching

Is your goal just to stitch the images together or is it to figure out specifically how to do it given the rotation and intrinsics matrices?
